# Перенос лицензии VS 2019 community в оффлайн

Tags: visual-studio, администрирование

Есть два рабочих места: на одном есть интернет, а на втором нет интернета. И эти рабочие места не объединены в сеть. Вопрос как перенести лицензию VS 2019 community с первого рабочего места на второе?
Для версии 2017 в точности в том же контексте эта задача решалась путём переноса папки %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VSCommon
Но для версии 2019 это не проходит.